# How to add a random number to input?

Tags: javascript, native

Make two inputs and two buttons-plus and minus for each of the inputs. Inputs should not have id attributes.

When loading the page, the first input has the value 1. When loading the page, the second input has the value -1.

For the first input, when you click on plus, a random number from 1 to 10 should be added to the current value. When you click on the minus sign, a random number from 1 to 10 should be subtracted from the current value.

The minimum value in the input should not be less than 1, if the subtraction should result in a number less than 1, then the input should be 1.

For the second input, when you click on plus, a random number from -1 to -10 should be added to the current value. When you click on minus, a random number from -1 to -10 should be subtracted from the current value.

The minimum value in the input must not be less than 0.

Must be done on pure JS.

```
const positivePlus = document.querySelector('.positive__plus');
const positiveMinus = document.querySelector('positive__minus');
const positiveInput = document.querySelector('.positive__input');
function positiveRandom () {
    const maxRandom = 10;
    return Math.round(Math.random() * maxRandom);
}
positivePlus.onclick = function() {
    positiveInput.innerHTML = positiveRandom();
}

<button class="positive__plus">+</button>
<div class="positive__input" type="text" value="1"></div>
<button class="positive__minus">-</button>
```

But this code is not what you need. It just adds a random number. And I need it to add to the previous value, which can not be more than 10. And for some reason I can't figure out how to implement it in the input. The value in the input does not change.

Comment: I apologize. Translated into English

Comment: No worries. I have removed the comment. --- May you also share a [mcve] of the issue?

Comment: Added more information to the post

Comment: Please translate the title too

Comment: Try changing the element `.positive__input` into an input instead of a `div`, and use `positiveInput.value` instead of `positiveInput.innerHTML`?

Comment: positiveInput.value helped, but how else to do so that when the maximum number 10 is reached in the input, the addition of numbers ends?